# CXF client deserializes a SOAP message to null with WS addressing

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I have a CXF client that uses `MAPAggregator` and `MAPCodec` for in and out interceptors to call a SOAP web service that uses WS addressing. I'm also logging the SOAP messages. It seems that the message returns correctly (the logger logs the correct response), but CXF deserializes it to `null`instead of the expected response class.

Why could that be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by removing `MAPAggregator` and `MAPCodec` in interceptors.